# ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor at the time of switchover using data guard broker

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a oracle data guard setup with nodes - one as primary and other as physical standby. I also, have configured the data guard broker on it.

The problem is when I tried to switch over , I just get the above error. In switch over process using DGMGRL (data guard broker), it successfully do the job of switch over but it is not able to start the satndby database after the switch over.I manually have to start and mount the standby database.

I also checked the tnsping and service name in the tnsnames.ora which is correct.
content of tnsnames.ora file is:

```
 PRI =
   (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = vcslx502-rana-vm1)(PORT = 1521))
      (CONNECT_DATA =
        (SERVER = DEDICATED)
        (SERVICE_NAME = pri)
      )
   )


 STBY =
   (DESCRIPTION=
       (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP) (HOST = vcslx502-rana-vm2) (PORT = 1521))
       (CONNECT_DATA =
          (SERVER = DEDICATED)
          (SERVICE_NAME = stby)
       )
   )
```

and the query result of service name is as follows: 
at primary:

```
SQL>  select value from v$parameter where name='service_names';

VALUE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
pri
```

and at standby:

```
SQL> select value from v$parameter where name='service_names';

VALUE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
stby
```

I also, have checked the services and found that these both services running. below is the result of that...
at primary:

```
[oracle@vcslx502-rana-vm1 admin]$ lsnrctl services

LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 11.2.0.4.0 - Production on 24-SEP-2014 11:45:15

Copyright (c) 1991, 2013, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC1521)))
Services Summary...
Service "pri" has 2 instance(s).
  Instance "pri", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
    Handler(s):
      "DEDICATED" established:0 refused:0
         LOCAL SERVER
  Instance "pri", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
    Handler(s):
      "DEDICATED" established:1 refused:0 state:ready
         LOCAL SERVER
Service "priXDB" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "pri", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
    Handler(s):
      "D000" established:0 refused:0 current:0 max:1022 state:ready
         DISPATCHER <machine: vcslx502-rana-vm1, pid: 29432>
         (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=vcslx502-rana-vm1)(PORT=28706))
Service "pri_DGB" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "pri", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
    Handler(s):
      "DEDICATED" established:1 refused:0 state:ready
         LOCAL SERVER
The command completed successfully
```

and at standby:

```
[oracle@vcslx502-rana-vm2 admin]$ lsnrctl services

LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 11.2.0.4.0 - Production on 24-SEP-2014 11:40:30

Copyright (c) 1991, 2013, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC1521)))
Services Summary...
Service "stby" has 2 instance(s).
  Instance "stby", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
    Handler(s):
      "DEDICATED" established:0 refused:0
         LOCAL SERVER
  Instance "stby", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
    Handler(s):
      "DEDICATED" established:1 refused:0 state:ready
         LOCAL SERVER
Service "stby_DGB" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "stby", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
    Handler(s):
      "DEDICATED" established:1 refused:0 state:ready
         LOCAL SERVER
The command completed successfully
```

Can someone please help me so that every time whenever I do switchover using DGMGRL, I don't have to start and mount the standby database?

one more thing, I can do switchover process manually by running every command needed without getting any such error.

Thanks, Rana

Comment: This topic is suitable for http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: okk..I was not aware of that. I saw some questions like this here that's why I posted it.

Answer (score 0):

The listener.ora file should be like this:

```
<unique_name>_LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = <hostname>)(PORT = <port>))
    )
  )

SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (GLOBAL_DBNAME = <unique_name>_DGMGRL.<domain>)
      (SID_NAME = <oracle_sid>)
      (ORACLE_HOME = <oracle_home>)
    )
  )
```

You can find it in the database. In my case they are following:

```
SQL>  select name as parameter,value from v$parameter
      where name in ('service_names','db_domain','db_unique_name');

PARAMETER       VALUE
--------------- --------------------
db_domain       rgolovko.com
service_names   RGTST.rgolovko.com
db_unique_name  RGTST
```

After I've added the domain name to the listener and service_name in databases
the dataguard performs switchover correctly.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I tried by adding domain name in listener.ora but in my case, I didn't get success and I don't why. I got solution by changing the "StaticConnectIdentifier" property of database. I changed "service_name" in this property to "servicename.localdomain" and got rid of above problem.